# Control DOIT ESP32 DevKit V1 using Blynk app

Tags: arduino, wireless, esp32

I'm a beginner and I'm working on a project to light an LED using DOIT ESP32 devkit v1. I want to turn on and off the LED using a phone app via wifi (using Blynk application). I'm using the following code on Arduino IDE (version 1.8.13):

```
#define BLYNK_PRINT Serial
#define LED 2

#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <BlynkSimpleEsp32.h>

// You should get Auth Token in the Blynk App.
// Go to the Project Settings (nut icon).
char auth[] = "...";

// Your WiFi credentials.
// Set password to "" for open networks.
char ssid[] = "...";
char pass[] = "...";

void setup() {  
  pinMode(LED, OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(LED, HIGH);
  Serial.begin(115200);

  delay(10);
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);
  int wifi_ctr = 0;
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }

  Serial.println("WiFi connected");  

  Blynk.begin("Your auth token key", ssid, pass);

}

void loop(){
    Blynk.run();
}
```

The connection to the wifi succeeded, But when I press the serial monitor button I get an error saying "Invalid auth token"

[image]

I don't understand what am I doing wrong, I've check the auth key few times, that's the right one. In the Blynk project I've chose ESP32 Dev Kit and in the Arduino IDE I chose DOIT ESP32 Dev Kit V1 along with port COM4 (I've made sure that's the right one).  I think the problem is that I'm not using Blynk right, What do I need to do?

Thank you.

Comment: which part of the code sends the token? ... have you tried running blynk example code?

Comment: Check `char auth[] = "...";` and `Blynk.begin("Your auth token key", ssid, pass);`

Answer (score 1):

I did Have a problem in `Blynk.begin("Your auth token key", ssid, pass);` missed one letter in the auth token. (probably didn't copy correctly) I read it 100 times and still missed it, thank you everyone for your help.